# How can I set multiple Gravity Forms values without doing a new database query for each one?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I have user information stored in a separate database from my Wordpress installation. I'm writing a plugin that queries this database and pre-fills values in a specific gravity form.

It looks like the following filter does what I need:

add_filter("gform_field_value_$PARAMETER", "FUNCTION");

The problem with this is that I need to call a function for each parameter value. That means that I query the database for each value.

So if I have eight pre-filled values, the database gets queried eight times. That seems inefficient.

Is there a way that I can query the database once, get all the values I need, then pass back the variables to the filters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my preferred way to handle this. Wrap your code in a class and store your query results in a variable in that class. You can then check if that variable already contains data and if so, simply return that already retrieved data rather than querying the database again.

```
class My_GF_Field_Values {

    var $data = null;

    function __construct() {

        add_filter( 'gform_field_value_param1', array( $this, 'func1' ) );
        add_filter( 'gform_field_value_param2', array( $this, 'func2' ) );

    }

    function func1() {

        $data = $this->get_data();

        return $data['param1'];
    }

    function func2() {

        $data = $this->get_data();

        return $data['param2'];
    }

    function get_data() {

        if( $this->data == null ) {
            $this->data = array(); // actually do your query and get the data
        }

        return $this->data;
    }

}
```

Comment: This makes sense... Thanks for your response! One question... When would I instantiate the object?

Comment: You can instantiate it right away (below the class definition).